# Deployed default guestbook - what does major minor mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

So when I deployed the default guestbook application I get a server error. When I checked the logs, I received the following error:
"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guestbook/SignGuestbookServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

What does this mean and how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

major.minor refers to the version number. In this case, 51 is the major version number, and 0 is the minor version number. It basically means that the code you are using is either too old or too new. Try to look for a supported version.

Comment: What do you mean supported version? Do you mean java version?

Comment: @Apothem Basically. It looks like you probably compiled your classes using one version of the JDK and then ran them on another? Try clearing out your compiled binary files and recompiling with a different (supported) JDK. Comment again if you're still having problems.